# Replace verify email address by sms

Tags: liferay

i want to verify user via sms, for example: "active user_id" send 8xxx
I try to set EMAILADDRESSVERIFIED in USER_ table equal 1 when receive active sms but not work, i check TICKET table when create new user, this table contain ticket key when active via email, but ticket key's length is too long, i want to send to user(respone to active sms) a short code, so i must create new table to map new code to ticket key.
In verify_email_address.jsp, i map new active code with ticket key before send to server but not work.
So anyone can show me a simple way to solve that, sorry for my english :)

Comment: There is not enough information here to assist you. Please post your code and, ideally, a stack trace showing where the exception is being raised. I also suggest you read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and these [hints on asking a good question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints).

Comment: thank RB, i have just edited :)

Comment: please edit again and post some code as RB suggested

Comment: I have solved my problem, i create new table to map user_id and activation status and ticket key :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I creat new table to map user_id and activation status, and custom login page, thank all !